# sendmail yesterday normal! Today receive but not deliver

Tags: email-server, sendmail, gmail

yesterday i was receiving emails from my domain and directing it to the gmail server and others normally. Today he simply stopped delivering, he receives but does not forward.

I'm using good old sendmail effectively, is there any kind of pattern where it is recommended to restart the server periodically? And if I do, I risk losing the queued messages (ps I'm not using any tmpfs)?

PS: Its not stuck only for gmail, but all destinations.

The sending command:

```
sendmail to@gmail.com < ./mailsample.txt
```

mailsample.txt content:

```
To: "to name" <to@gmail.com>
From: "my name" <sender@mydomain.com>
Subject: now its a test

Actual message.
```

The message is stuck in the mailq like this

```
V8
T1566564615
K1566566003
N3
P210595
I202/1/265633
MDeferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.Fbs
$_localhost [127.0.0.1]
$rESMTP
$sip-177-34-27-94.sa-east-1.compute.internal
${daemon_flags}
${if_addr}127.0.0.1
S<sender@mydomain.com>
MDeferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
rRFC822; to@gmail.com
RPFD:<to@gmail.com>
H?P?Return-Path: <<81>g>
H??Received: from ip-177-34-27-94.sa-east-1.compute.internal (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by ip-177-34-27-94.sa-east-1.compute.internal (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id x7NCoInA017234
    for <to@gmail.com>; Fri, 23 Aug 2019 12:50:18 GMT
H??Received: (from mail@localhost)
    by ip-177-34-27-94.sa-east-1.compute.internal (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id x7NCoIdU017233
    for to@gmail.com; Fri, 23 Aug 2019 12:50:18 GMT
H??Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2019 12:50:18 GMT
H??Message-Id: <201908231250.x7NCoIdU017233@ip-177-34-27-94.sa-east-1.compute.internal>
H??X-Authentication-Warning: ip-177-34-27-94.sa-east-1.compute.internal: mail set sender to sender@mydomain.com using -f
H??To: "to name" <to@gmail.com>
H??From: sender@mydomain.com
H??MIME-Version: 1.0
H??Subject: now its a test
.
```

The mail queue is showing ...

```
Aug 23 12:50:18 ip-177-34-27-94 sendmail[17234]: x7NCoInA017234: from=<sender@mydomain.com>, size=593, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201908231250.x7NCoIdU017233@ip-177-34-27-94.sa-east-1.compute.internal>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug 23 12:50:18 ip-177-34-27-94 sendmail[17233]: x7NCoIdU017233: to=to@gmail.com, ctladdr=sender@mydomain.com (8/12), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30178, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (x7NCoInA017234 Message accepted for delivery)
Aug 23 12:55:18 ip-177-34-27-94 sendmail[17236]: x7NCoInA017234: to=<to@gmail.com>, delay=00:05:00, xdelay=00:05:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120593, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [172.217.194.26], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Aug 23 13:13:22 ip-177-34-27-94 sendmail[17557]: x7NCoInA017234: to=<to@gmail.com>, delay=00:23:04, xdelay=00:05:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=210593, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [172.217.194.27], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Aug 23 13:25:18 ip-177-34-27-94 sendmail[17520]: x7NCoInA017234: to=<to@gmail.com>, delay=00:35:00, xdelay=00:05:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=300593, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [172.217.194.27], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

IP Tables:

```
[root@ip-172-31-28-93 ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Another thing that sems to be importante is the sendmail -v -q output

```
Running /var/spool/mqueue/x7NDGEZx017609 (sequence 4 of 146)
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 Resetting
<to@mydomain.com>... Using cached ESMTP connection to webfopag-com-br.mail.protection.outlook.com. via esmtp...
>>> MAIL From:<> SIZE=7263
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
>>> RCPT To:<to@mydomain.com>
>>> DATA
550 5.7.606 Access denied, banned sending IP [54.93.220.30]. To request removal from this list please visit https://sender.office.com/ and follow the directions. For more information please go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=526655 (AS16012609)
[BL2NAM02FT059.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com] <to@mydomain.com> ... User unknown 503 5.5.2 Need rcpt command [BL2NAM02FT059.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com]
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 Resetting
MAILER-DAEMON... aliased to postmaster
postmaster... aliased to root
postmaster... aliased to root
root... Connecting to local...
root... Sent
```

This server receives messages from several other servers and acts as an outbound portal for my multi-domain messages on my network. It is not an open relay, we have a program developed by us that receives the messages with username and password, validates if they are ok and only then makes the delivery to the local server that should deliver the message in the destination domain. But today the messages are on holding!

Yesterday the flow was normal, today the mailq  grows at the minute. What may be stopping the machine?

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue. Apart from that you should address the ban of your IP by Microsoft.

Comment: I already notified microsoft, but it seems that the ip has been blocked again, so I believe it is not a firewall problem. As you can see in the sendmail output -v -q the server was connected. Iptabels is also empty and there are no restrictive rules on the server exit.

Comment: I have adjusted the comment box to better show the last log box. Thanks

Comment: You have two different problems there, one is Microsoft, which seems to have you banned. The second is the timeout to gmail. Again, this is usually a firewall issue. The firewall can be anywhere between your machine and the target server. You should try to send mails to different providers to isolate where the problem actually is.

Comment: It is not firewall i confirmed using nmap. namp to localhost on 25 port is ok, but it times out to Dreamhost as well